# Using the "dash" from Unity interface in classic mode?

Tags: unity, gnome

I've so far opted out of the complete Unity experience, preferring the Ubuntu classic (gnome-shell) on my desktop.

However, Unity's "dash" (the thing that opens from the Ubuntu button in the top-left corner) seems interesting, especially the "more apps" -functionality that displays shortcuts to software center alongside with already installed apps.

Can that part of Unity be used with Ubuntu classic 11.04 without running into all sorts of conflicts and problems? How?

Comment: Since Ubuntu classic isn't exactly around anymore, I guess this question can be closed as no longer relevant.

Comment: I disagree. While the Ubuntu Classic session you referred to in this post was based on GNOME 2 (and hence removed with 11.10's transition to GNOME 3), 11.10 and later allow for the installation of [GNOME Classic](http://askubuntu.com/a/65087/18612), which is the GNOME 3 equivalent of the old 2-panel interface. Answers applicable to Ubuntu Classic should be valid for GNOME Classic users, and probably vice versa.

Comment: `unity-2d-shell`

Answer (score 3):

It won't be completely similar in appearance and it won't have the "More Apps" functionality, but [Cardapio](https://launchpad.net/cardapio) has the ability to search for applications by typing, among other things.

Comment: Well, as you said it doesn't have the "uninstalled apps" -functionality. Also, counting on future development I consider it personally a better idea to get used to something that comes with Ubuntu rather than a third party tools. Thanks for the tip anyway!

Answer (score 1):

What about this flaming new extensions for gnome-shell?
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/330/bolt/

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 12.04 the following might help:

Revert to Gnome Classic Desktop as described here: [How to revert to GNOME Classic Desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/58172/how-to-revert-to-gnome-classic-desktop/108916#108916)

Start `unity-2d-shell` as described here: [Ubuntu 12.04 Gnome Classic and Unity Launcher](https://askubuntu.com/q/261897/55343)

You will get the unity launcher, from which you can open the dash. Or use the `super/windows` key.

For autohiding the launcher in 12.04 see this question: [Autohide Unity Launcher in Gnome Classic](https://askubuntu.com/q/262585/55343).